# How to securely connect a Webserver to a Database server through WAN

Tags: networking, security, vpn, webserver, sql-server

I have two servers, one that will be hosting a database. The other a website.
The one hosting the website should be able to accept and sent requests from any IP. The database server should ideally only accept connections from known sources such as the web server.

Here's the options I have found so far :

1) IP / DNS restrictions on the SQL server: I am assuming that the data could be viewed externally due to the lack of encryption however I do not thinks it is a must for now. Plus I believe adding encryption to every request would slow down the requests. This would probably be the easiest approach.

2) VPN : Have a VPN server setupped on the SQL server? Im still not quite sure how VPN works exactly. I am currently assuming that the SQL server would block any connections except the ones that are on the VPN Client. Will the web server still be able to serve web requests as usual while interacting with the SQL server through the VPN? Is it possible with this approach to only authentificate and then leave the data unencrypted.

Are these options possible, are they correct? If not what would be a better approach.The second option is the one I am the most insecure with since I am not quite sure how exactly the webserver will know which outgoing transactions will have to go through the VPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL encryption from the webserver does not significantly impact the performance of your server.  At least not until you have dozens possible hundreds of concurrent connections.

One solution is to load [adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) or [phpMyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/).

2. Write a program in php,perl, or python

Comment: Although this solution does not apply to me since I am currently using MSSQL on linux which does not currently support SSL (My fault for creating a setup for something is not ready yet)  I will mark this as a correct solution since I had not thought of it and I believe that yes, a simple SSL certificate combined with IP restrictions if necessary would probably have done the trick and would have been much easier to configure than a VPN.

Comment: @Max adminer supports connecting to mssql servers.  Also you can have Apache provide the SSL, and adminer or etc will give you access to the database in a web page based format.